# How to get getfriendlyurl() url in link attribute using sxa rendring variant

Tags: sxa

I'm trying to get a prefix in the wrapped url using a SXA variant

1. ItemLink is a general field type
2. ItemLink added in wrapped variant

This image is a custom component not using sxa variant feature so I want the same in sxa variant feature

[image]

Below is the image related to sxa variant:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which version are you using? (asking to know if you can use Scriban templates)

Comment: sitecore 10.2 version, I want to achieve in variant feature

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Scriban template variant to achieve this. More info on this for 10.2: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/102/sitecore-experience-accelerator/scriban-templates.html

This way you are using variants and do not need custom code.

I tried using tokens in such variant fields once (https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2018/10/using-tokens-in-sitecore-sxa-variant.html) but bumped rather quickly to the limitations. You can always try extending this with custom code but I see absolutely no reason to do it when there is an ootb solution with Scriban.

ps: note that you can combine Scriban with the other variant types so you can limit the template to any (small) part you would like